# How do I get an Nginx non root ( "/" ) location to serve files?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I'm a Nginx beginner. I rented a little VPS with Ubuntu 12.04 to test. I rented no domain so I make requests directly using the ip. For this question let's assume the ip is **209.208.26.89**. Installed the lastest stable Nginx from the official ppa.

After installing Nginx and checking it working ok (going with my browser to `http://209.208.26.89`) I removed the default configuration from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled. I used this configuration first:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /home/www-data/public-www;
        index index.html index.htm; #index.html is inside /home/www-data/public-www

        server_name 209.208.26.89; #remember, no domain

        location /example {
                root /home/www-data/public-www/example;
                index hello.html; #hello.html is inside /home/www-data/public-www/example
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

All directories and permissions are correctly set.

When I accessed to `http://209.208.26.89/example` I was greeted with a 404. The weird thing is that accessing to `http://209.208.26.89/` would yield the file hello.html.

How is that suppoused to happen? I'm setting that file to location `/example`!

However, I tried then with this:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /home/www-data/public-www;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name 209.208.26.89; #remember, no domain

        location /example {
                alias /home/www-data/public-www/example; #HERE'S THE CHANGED LINE
                index hello.html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Using this configuration, `http:// 209.208.26.89/example` will correctly yield hello.html. BUT `http:// 209.208.26.89` will yield the same file.

To make it clear, what I want to do is: when requesting `http:// 209.208.26.89/example` Nginx should serve me /home/www-data/public-www/example/example.html. I made it with my second configuration, with the drawback of it being server **also** at `http:// 209.208.26.89`. But my second requirement is 'http:// 209.208.26.89/' to serve me nothing (should return 404).

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but no guide or documentation seems to point me in the right direction. Can anyone help me understand what's happening?

Comment: Why are you setting up a special `location`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I want `/home/www-data/public-www/example` to be served at `/example`. That's all :)

Comment: You don't need a `location` for that!

Comment: Then how can I do it?

Comment: You still haven't explained what it is you're trying to do!

Comment: Ok @MichaelHampton I updated my question, I hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's caused by this line:

`root /home/www-data/public-www;`

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root

you can remove that, or specify somewhere else.